# Is it possible to share WiFi "USB adapter" serial port over the internet and use it to access lan network?

Tags: usb

If I had a PC with WiFi adapter, and I shared the USB over the internet and that port have the Wifi adapter. Would I have a "LAN via WAN" connection?

Answer (score 0):

Most companies use something called VPN it's "a tunnel connection" to make your home PC connect to your workplace, in safety and encrypted way,

You don't need to connect to your USB port at work to be at the same LAN network, anyway ask the IT guy in your company to figure it for your home PC, if your company have already VPN tunnel you can easily connect to that LAN network.

If not and want to use very easy way; you can use service called "remote access" you can find a lot of programs on the web for that, some apps only to show your work PC screen, while other gives you fully control of that PC like files and printers, like "TeamViewer" or other programs.

VPN it's not that hard to setup, you can use Third-Party program to be at the same LAN network like "hamachi"

Comment: The problem is that I AM the IT guy!  :-)  I do the WiFi and security cams at neighborhood bar (6 bartenders + myself as needed which includes maintenance etc.).  So there's no VPN, or even my own PC. A laptop is shared among us all.  I saw that Raspberry Pi has a free app allowing a USB port to be shared, as do some routers. These would be the types of options in my "do-ability zone".  Is it possible to use one NIC to access the Raspberry Pi, and then have a second one for the dongle to "plug into"?

Comment: "The problem is that I AM the IT guy!" lol :P okay I didn't say you can't do that, there is a lot of programs that's make you shared your USB over LAN or WEB, I don't know about Raspberry Pi I didn't share the USB but with Arduino Yup you can, I have made that before, and yup you can make the same with routers Cisco e3200 with dd-wrt firmware But for now I didn't know exactly WHY?!! there is a lot of easy options there,

Comment: Yes, the shared USB part of my plan seems within my ability (basically installing an app and learning to run it). But the part that has me scratching my head is how to use the WiFi dongle once I'm connected to it, how do make my PC forget about the internet connection for remote USB access, and pretend that the dongle is the "one and only"?  My home route does its subnet thing on the x.x.0.x segment; work uses x.x.2.x  Ans for hardware, my NIC, or adapter, or whatever is already in use, so I'm guessing I'll need another gizmo tthat he dongle can use.  And then... well, let me just say, "HELP!"

Answer (score -1):

No. All a wifi dongle does is pick up wifi. It allows you to connect to a wireless modem / router.  You also have to figure in range restrictions, usually you start losing most of your signal at around 100ft.  (0 to 30 (to max 50) ft is the recommended "range". The wi-fi dongle may allow you to bring the remote pc out of sleep mode, just the same as most nic / wireless nic cards do, which would allow you to access files on the remote computer.

This would be something you would use to access your work computer from your home.  HOWEVER... it is not secure.  Most workplaces have a server to connect to in house computers, you connect to the server, then connect from the server to the work PC.  This is just an example of why you might want to access a remote PC.

Although not very secure, this does have other uses, such as turning on a web cam to check on the baby sitter when you are on a trip, but I wouldn't recommend doing any jobs involving security or privacy.

Comment: I should clarify:  I do want to pick up a WiFi signal. I want to be at home and pick up the guest WiFi signal at work. So it would be like stretching my USB port all the way to work and use the dongle there. I want to be part of the LAN at work.